# How to pass custom command line arguments to Setup.hs

Tags: haskell, command-line-interface, haskell-stack

I have `stack` project. I want to be able to pass my own arguments to `Setup.hs` so that I could customize building process. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I haven't found better solution than using custom environment variable. And in `Setup.hs` you can call [`lookupEnv`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/System-Environment.html#v:lookupEnv) function to check the desired environment variable.

Also, there is [Shake](http://shakebuild.com/) build tool which is designed to customize building process and should be preferred to `Setup.hs` configurations.

Answer (score 0):

It may depends on what's your customized build process. `Setup.hs` has a main function, so you can parse arguments by `getArgs` and do specific things; or if you'd like to pass the arguments along then you can use `UserHooks`, such as:

```
defaultMainWithHooks (simpleUserHooks {preBuild = xxx, postClean = yyy, ... } )
```

Each hook accepts `Args`.

Comment: I know that I can read arguments with `getArgs`. But how can I pass my custom user-defined arguments so they can be used in hooks?